# How to Improve MLP ANN accuracy

Tags: python, gradient-descent, accuracy, mlp, ann

I am trying to improve the accuracy of my model over the UCI Breast Cancer Dataset. There's 426 records, and it is a binary classification model.

```
X_train.shape
(426, 30)
X_test.shape
(143, 30)
y_train.shape
(426, 1)
y_test.shape
(143, 1)
```

- I have tried three types of gradient descents to compare the
  accuracies and it remains stagnant on 0.62.
- Batch sizes: Batch gradient descent over the whole dataset, for
  stochastic it is 1/1 and mini batch takes 16 batches. All of them show the same accuracy.
- The activation layers used are relu, relu, sigmoid, for 6,4,2 neurons in each layer.
- The loss function used is cross entropy.
- I have normalised the dataset using StandardScaler and Min Max Scaler from scikit learn.
- Learning rate is 0.00095, and epochs is 50. The following shows the learning rate after each epoch for stochastic gradient descent

```
    Cost after epoch 0: 0.690206  
    Cost after epoch 10: 0.664892  
    Cost after epoch 20: 0.661360  
    Cost after epoch 30: 0.660859  
    Cost after epoch 40: 0.660782
```

[image]

```
Accuracy
0.6293706293706294
```

The Confusion Matrix gives 0 values for TN and FN, and I am aware this might be wrong, but do not understand where its going wrong.

```
90 0 53 0
```

Apart from all this, I have tried experimenting with different epoch numbers, hidden neurons, layers and learning rates, but accuracy does not improve.

Answer (score 1):

I think two factors are working against you. First, you are working with **tabular data**, for which neural networks not often yield optimal results. At least when we are not talking aboult very large datasets. I would approach this problem with tree-based algorithms since they are so much simpler to handle and regularly beat neural networks in (tabular) benchmark datasets (...). Second, what I already mentioned, you are working with a **comparatively small dataset**. Neural networks are generally hungry for data. 569 Instances minus your test set won't give much space for learning.

I would go with RandomForest or XGBoost. In case you just want to experiment with neural networks on this dataset regardless you might be already at the possible optimum. **A curcial part for training neural networks is the data preprocessing, which you did not talk about that.** There might be room for improvement by applying feature scaling and general feature engineering. Although, I have to say I'm not familiar with this particular dataset.

Comment: A part of your answer did apply to me, I normalised my data using MinMax Scaler, and adjusted the threshold using ROC curve which helped improve accuracy, not by a lot but made a bit of a difference.